# When I switch to new user, I am unable to see the name in the prompt - Why?

Tags: command-line, 12.10, prompt

I have just created a fresh installation of `Ubuntu 12.10`

I have created a www-data user account.

When I switch to www-data, I cannot see `www-data` at the front of the prompt.

1. What is the technical name to call that part of the prompt?
2. How can I make it appear for www-data?

See this for reference.

As you can see, root has this. But not www-data

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://superuser.com/a/68486/8184)

but i will explain the exact steps I used.

first at root i did a

```
echo $SHELL
```

I saw that I have /bin/bash

then i switch to www-data

```
sudo su www-data
```

then i do a

```
echo $SHELL
```

I saw that I had

```
/bin/sh
```

instead.

So I did a

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

I was prompted for my www-data password so I gave it.

```
Password:
```

after that I switch back to root

```
exit
```

then i log back into www-data

```
sudo su www-data
```

I checked the $SHELL again

```
echo $SHELL
```

I saw that now it is

```
/bin/bash
```

and also my prompt is back

Answer (score 2):

1. I believe just 'the prompt'.
2. Copy `root`'s `~/.bashrc` file to `www-data`'s `~/.bashrc` file.

In other words:
(run in root) `cp ~/.bashrc /home/www-data/.bashrc`
assuming `/home/www-data` is `www-data`'s home folder, which it is.
Then just restart. (Actually, you only need to kill `bash`, but just restart anyway)

Comment: first of all, the home of www-data is not in /home/www-data but in /var/www strangely. and i cannot make it work using the copy root bashrc